# SIMPLE C PROGRAM WITH INCREMENT OPERATOR. could you explain the actual workflow of this program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { int i=0; printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", i++, i++, i++, i++, i, i++);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the disassembly ?

Comment: See [Why can't we mix increment operators like i++ with other operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278384).

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can evaluate the code in whatsoever way it wants.

But what is specified by the standard, is that modifying the same variable twice in one operation is undefined behavior; ISO C++03, 5[expr]/4:

You should not write print the statements this way for unary operators.